# (SwiftUI) Kingfisher ForEach issue

Tags: swiftui, kingfisher

I want to print web images using ForEach.

*To print web images, I used a 3rd party library, kingfisher.

```
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct KingFisherTest: View {
    var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { _ in
            KFImage(URL(string: "https://cdn.imweb.me/upload/S2017101359e025984d346/bff36a6d2ced4.jpg"))
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .onAppear {
                    print("onAppear!")
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    print("onDisappear!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct KingFisherTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        KingFisherTest()
    }
}
```

However, there is an issue where onAppear() occurs twice when one image is printed.

[image: Issue]

I want onAppear() to do a specific function, but the issue causes the function to work twice.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: There is `onSuccess { result in }` method for `KFImage`, did you try it?

Comment: Using onSuccess() seems to solve this issue. Thanks!!

Comment: But, I'm curious as to what causes onAppear() to appear twice.

Comment: It's because of SwiftUI probably, not you :)